# PERMISOS - Dialogo de "Superposición de pantalla detectada"

Tags: android, permisos, android-permissions

estoy con una aplicación y al instalarla y pedir los permisos me sale el siguiente dialogo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que yo no utilizo la superposición de pantalla, o por lo menos que yo sepa no la estoy utilizando en ningún sitio por eso me esta molestando un poco.

Los permisos que tengo en mi aplicación son los siguientes:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
```

¿Cuál de ellos puede estar causando que aparezca ese diálogo? Si es que lo está causando uno de esos...

Comment: Una pregunta importante que dispositivo version y Marca usas?,

Comment: tambien ten en cuenta de los plugins que utilizas, al compilar se une los manifests creando solo uno.

Comment: otro posible, es que si usas notificaciones modificadas, como la calculadora de pokemon, que desde la notificación se despliega una calculadora etc...

Comment: Pues utilizo un Sony Xperia z3 y también lo probé en un Bq Aquarius E5 y en ambos pasaba... voy a mirar a ver si alguna librería de las que tengo puede estar provocándolo.

Answer (score 0):

Esto en sistemas operativos configurados en ingles es "System overlay detected", esto puedes deshabilitarlo desde la configuración y aplica para OS 6.0+:

Desde el menú ve a :

`Ajustes` > `Aplicaciones` >  da clic al engrane (esquina superior derecha),

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ve a `Escribir sobre otras aplicaciones`, selecciona la aplicación y  des habilita esta opción.

[image: Editando...]

En telefonos Samsung el problema puede ser el panel lateral, para deshabilitarlo.
`Ajustes` > `Aplicaciones` > `Administrador de aplicaciones` , da clic al engrane y entrar a gestión de la superposición de pantalla, ahi se puede deshabilitar.

Comment: Hasta ahí había llegado pero el botón de activar y desactivar siempre esta desactivado y no me deja cambiarlo. Aunque de todas maneras ese permiso no me afecta en nada en mi aplicación por que no lo uso...  pero es molesto que salga cuando se instala la aplicación.